# How i can print this in one?

Tags: javascript, loops

I would like to know, how I can write this in one line with the symbol of dollar($) separating each word and with this symbol in the end?I've tried to change " " to $ with replace - no success. In this example it is printing $ before every word but still in a column :/

```js
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {
    this.words = words;
  }
  print() {
    var a = this.words;

    for (let v of a) {
      v = "$" + v;
      console.log(v);
    }
  }
}

var x = new Add("hehe",
  "hoho", "haha", "hihi",
  "huhu");

var y = new Add("this", "is",
  "awesome");

var z = new Add("lorem",
  "ipsum", "dolor", "sit",
  "amet", "consectetur",
  "adipiscing", "elit");

x.print();
y.print();
z.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the object for other things, put the strings in an array and use `array.join()` with `'$'` as the join argument, and concatentate `?` to the end.

Working snippet:

```js
let x = ["hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu"];

console.log(`${x.join('$')}?`);
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r why did you make silly edits to my post. You 'changed'  array.join() to array.join(),  concatenate to concatentate , and x to word (claiming it to be more consitent with the question when the question defined the list of words as 'x'). retract your edit or reply explianing yourself or I will find a way to report you. Your intereference is not helpful.

Comment: @Biedrzyk I had a comment, not showing here, asking "How I can print this one". I'm not sure if it was you but if so, you can direct the result of my answer wherever you want. If you need it displayed on an html document, you reference the element you want it displayed in and set it's `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` property to the result of the process. For example: `document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = `${words.join('$')}?`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed `array.join()` into a reference linking the MDN documentation. Having references to the documentation never hurts and allows OP to easily navigate to a page that contains more info. You claim that I changed "concatenate" into "concatentate", but you are wrong. It's the other way around. I've changed "concatentate" into "concatenate", the current spelling in the question is wrong. The question defines a list of words as `this.words`. A variable `words` is a lot more similar than `x`. `x` is an instance of `Add`, not a list of words.

Comment: thx guys for the help and suggestions - i will try it tomorrow, and i will certainly let You know if this is what I Was searching for :D

Comment: Thx for the help guys - it worked 